# Stillwell Naive Lie theory exercise 4.3.2 page 81

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a smooth path $A(t)$ in a Lie group, where $A(0)=I$, let $C(t)=A(t)^{-1}$. Show that $C'(0)=-A'(0)$. I don't know how to prove that unless I assume that $A(t)=e^{tX}$ for some matrix $X$ in the Lie algebra, so $C(t)=e^{-tX}$. But Stillwell doesn't seem to assume that.

Comment: You can just differentiate it as you usually do in $\mathbb{R}.$ We have a path $A:[-1,1]\longrightarrow G.$ You can either just differentiate or build the limit in the definition of a derivative. Both will be fine. Note: don't forget that $A^{-2}(0)=I^{-2}=I.$

Comment: Are you using exercise $4.3.1$?

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate both sides of the equation $A(t) C(t) = \text{Id}$ and then set $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If we use the fact that the derivative of the inversion $\iota$ in a Lie group is times $-1$ in its Lie algebra then we get by the chain rule

$$
C'(0)=D_0(\iota\circ A(t))=D_{A(0)}(\iota)\cdot D_0(A(t))=-(A(0))\cdot A'(0)=-I\cdot A'(0)=-A'(0) 
$$

We can also use the product rule. We have $A(t)\cdot C(t)\equiv \mathbb{1}_G$. Hence
$$
D_{t=0}(\mathbb{1}_G)= 0 = A(0)\cdot C'(0)+A'(0)\cdot C(0)=I\cdot C'(0)+A'(0)\cdot I
$$
or
$$
C'(0)=-A'(0)
$$